# On the notion of (locally) small categories

Tags: category-theory

I've read many related questions like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2369644/locally-small-categories) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989244/difference-between-large-and-small-categories), but I am still confused about what (locally) small categories are. My text is "Category Theory Lecture Notes" by Turi in which one reads

> A category $\mathbb{C}$ is small if its collection of objects $\text{Obj}_{\mathbb{C}}$ and
> collection of arrows $\text{Arr}_{\mathbb{C}}$ are sets; it is locally small if the collection
> $\mathbb{C}(A,B)$ of arrows from $A$ to $B$ is a set for each pair of
> objects $A$ and $B$.

The text says the category of natural numbers $\boldsymbol{N}$ is small, and the category of finite sets $\boldsymbol{Finset}$ is locally small.

Let me elaborate on what I don't understand:

1. The condition of being small is pretty loose to me, say, aren't the collections of arrows and objects of a category always sets? If not, can you please show a simple commutative diagram (of a category) in which this is not the case?
2. Similarly for locally small categories, how can the collection $\mathbb{C}(A,B)$ not be a set? Any minimal example here is also appreciated.

Comment: The collection of all sets is not a set, right? Therefore, the category of sets is not small.

Comment: @azif00: Thanks for tour comment. 1- Does that mean if one imposes the restriction of "finiteness" on both objects and arrows of a category, we always get a small category? 2- What about the collection of all finite sets? Are they a set (or a "Class", as I have read in some answers)?

Comment: No, the collection of all finite sets is not a set (because it contains the injective image of any set).

Comment: @User What is your definition of "set"? What are your axioms for what you can do with sets? And what is your definition of "category"? If you spend a few minutes thinking about it either you will see why it matters, or you will realise you have more fundamental questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> aren't the collections of arrows and objects of a category always sets?

No. We want to study many examples of categories given by all mathematical objects of a certain type, e.g. all sets, all groups, all vector spaces, all topological spaces, that kind of thing. The collection of objects in each of these categories are [proper classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)), meaning they are "too large to be a set."

> Similarly for locally small categories, how can the collection $\mathbb{C}(A,B)$ not be a set? Any minimal example here is also appreciated.

There aren't any really "natural" examples here; essentially any category that arises in practice is locally small. It's standard to use "category" to mean "locally small category" without any further elaboration because it is a very mild and natural restriction.

However, if $C, D$ are two (locally small) categories, the functor "category" $[C, D]$, of all functors and all natural transformations, can fail to be locally small; Theo Johnson-Freyd gives an example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/146362/290). This is not a big deal in practice because we rarely need to consider the entire functor category unless $C$ is small, and in that case there are no issues.

These "size issues" in category theory can mostly be ignored a lot of the time but they are important. You can consult Mike Shulman's *[Set theory for category theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1279)* for more details.